# Jasper reports text field limit

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm having a **.jrxml** file in which I have a text field whose width I've set to the maximum possible and I've set the "print when details overflow" and "stretch with overflow flag".

But when generating the report in pdf format from a collection source the text field stretches to 3 lines and for first entry and for next entry it stretches to 5 lines. But the data which I have in collection object is of 7 lines each. While generating the same for .odt format the textfield stretches to 7 lines for both the entries.

What is the issue which I'm facing here?

Comment: Can you add screenshots to illustrate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. I had used Calibri as my font to text field. Changed it to Arial and it stretched to full text.

http://jasperforge.org/node/531750

Referred this link. It had a comment mentioning that certain fonts create problem while exporting to pdf.